# Can we stop an application integrated with OpenSSL from using openssl.conf/.cnf file using compile time option?

Tags: openssl, libcurl

An application integrated with OpenSSL should not read openssl.cnf file. This is a security risk.

Have came across OPENSSL_init_crypto(OPENSSL_INIT_NO_LOAD_CONFIG, NULL); but cannot use it since the application has CURL too which internally initializes OpenSSL.

Thus, only CURL is initialized but both OpenSSL and CURL are used simultaneously.

I did check out the Configure file of OpenSSL to look for compile time switch but did not find any.

Comment: You have to rebuild libcurl with the option `CURL_DISABLE_OPENSSL_AUTO_LOAD_CONFIG`

Comment: openssl.conf is read due to invocation of openssl EVP APIs.
Using CURL_DISABLE_OPENSSL_AUTO_LOAD_CONFIG  already

Comment: If you call `OPENSSL_init_crypto(OPENSSL_INIT_NO_LOAD_CONFIG, NULL)` prior `curl_global_init()` and any other function that uses OpenSSL, OpenSSL EVP will not load the config.

Comment: to summarize, the application uses both curl and openssl. There are set of calls to EVP apis and another set of calls to CURL apis. 

Point to notice here is that calling OPENSSL_init_crypto(OPENSSL_INIT_NO_LOAD_CONFIG, NULL) at the very start of code just before curl_global_init(defaults) still causes EVP apis to read the OpenSSL.cnf

Looks like the ossl call made at the global level is not affecting EVP calls in the other threads

Comment: I would call OPENSSL_init_ssl. Nothing can be done at the global level.

Answer (score 0):

no-autoload-config option can be used during compilation